# how can I solve this on npm when installing react js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

PS C:\Users\Daltons> npm install -g create-react-app

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 8s

4 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

1. Run `npm audit` for details. PS C:\Users\Daltons> create-react-app
   robo create-react-app : File
   C:\Users\Daltons\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.ps1 cannot be
   loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
   information, see about_Execution_Policies at
   https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1

   - create-react-app robo

- 
- CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  PS C:\Users\Daltons>

""I know problem is by permission of window""

Comment: You open terminal with admin priviledge?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito how to do that?

Comment: Start -> type CMD in search bar -> Right click on Command prompt -> Run As Administrator

Comment: No problem, happy to help you. May I post this as an answer so you can mark as valid?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito of course man!

Answer (score 0):

Try to open terminal with admin priviledge and launch your command.

To open terminal in admin mode you can:

Start -> type CMD in search bar -> Right click on Command prompt -> Run As Administrator